# How to set up the recipient id in public activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, railscasts

I am going over Public Activity Gem Railscast Vid. (http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity)

My current DB looks/stores everything but the recipient_id....it shows up as nil

```
#<PublicActivity::Activity id: 108, trackable_id: 133, trackable_type: "Relationship",
owner_id: 1, owner_type: "User", key: "relationship.create", parameters: {}, 
recipient_id: nil, recipient_type: nil, created_at: "2013-06-16 07:37:28", 
updated_at: "2013-06-16 07:37:28">
```

I would like the recipient_id to be the user who the action is being performed on....

Ex.

If I like **Tom's Post**.....I would like Tom's ID to become the recipient_id & I'll be the owner_id.

I have currently set a recipient ID....using the code in my Likes Controller....but it only sets the recipient Id to current user....which is not what i want :(

**LIKES CONTROLLER**

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked except: :destroy, owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }

  **tracked except: :destroy, recipient: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }**

  attr_accessible :dailypost_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :dailypost


  default_scope order: 'likes.created_at DESC'
end
```

Do I need to create a method or something. Please help.....new to rails

Comment: Please use the generic Ruby on Rails tag, as very few people search for question about a specific Rails version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
tracked recipient: ->(controller, model) { model && model.user }
```

assuming Tom is the user of tracked object. Otherwise change `model.user` as per your application